# WhatsApp: how to use downloaded sticker collection from messages in Gboard

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gboard

This question is about how to use a particular feature in WhatsApp.

Someone sent a message on a group in WhatsApp, and the message was a sticker. Clicking onto it gave me a better view of the picture, and three options. I clicked on the first one to download the sticker. Then the sticker onto the WhatsApp group almost seemed to turn into a big emoticon giving a smile with a heart hovering off and to the side, on top (actually, this was just WhatsApp scrolling, a bit below, would be nice if this spurious scrolling were fixed).

But now, I don't know where to go in Gboard to find the sticker collection I downloaded in WhatsApp in this manner.

I think I am confusing WhatsApp stickers with Gboard stickers.

How do I transfer WhatsApp stickers to Gboard, to view the stickers downloaded from WhatsApp?

Or, alternatively, how do I just open the stickers in WhatsApp?

Thank you for your help.

Stickers viewed in Gboard when I click in WhatsApp:

[image: Stickers viewed in Gboard when I click in WhatsApp]

Stickers viewed in Gboard when I browse Gboard stickers:

[image: Stickers viewed in Gboard when I browse Gboard stickers]

Answer (score 1):

To open the stickers in WhatsApp, click on the emoticon to the left of the space where you enter messages to be sent.

To open stickers in Gboard, click on the smiley or sticker icon above the keyboard or on the smiley above the comma selected by long pressing, and click on the sticker icon below.

Thanks.